# Frete fixo a partir de R$ 200 no Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Estou tentando configurar uma taxa fixa (flat rate) de 10 reais para uma área específica mas com uma condição de valor mínimo de pedido para R$ 200. O problema é que o cliente quer que esse valor apareça apenas quando o valor de compra for de, no mínimo R$ 200,00. Pra frete grátis isso fica fácil de configurar, mas pra taxa fixa não existe uma condicional, alguém já configurou algo parecido?